# Bean Properties Editor/Sheet like Netbeans'

Tags: java, netbeans, properties, editor

I want to develop a GUI-based java bean property editor(like the one used to edit bean properties in netbeans). Is there any open source java implementation of this?

Answer (score 0):

The Netbeans IDE is built using the Netbeans platform ( http://netbeans.org/features/platform/index.html ) which you can use to build your own applications that don't have to look like IDEs. The learning curve might be a little steep, but there are many tutorials and an active community. You can also just use the bean editor in your own Swing app without implementing the whole platform.

Comment: I would like to use the property widget inside my own code, but I had no luck finding how to do this. Do you have any pointers, please?